# Linux/eclipse oxygen/project errors

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I'm new to Linux(in general, but Mint specifically), but was able to muddle through getting eclipse to open (Java version openjdk version "9-internal"), Running Eclipse Oxygen1.A.  (I had to end up editing the eclipse.ini as mentioned in some other posts to get the application to start (eg: remove -add ALL MODULES, etc.)

The program starts fine now, but get the following errors when creating a project: (see below)

I've tried creating new workspaces, without any luck.. I was attempting to create a Java9 project, but also tried creating Java8 projects just for measure..

Any recommendations or suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any/all suggestions.
(PS: probably worth mentioning my core experience is in Windows, and I've configured the new Oxygen/Java9 in the windows 10 OS to behave as expected..)

```
Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException: null
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.JRTUtil.walkModuleImage(JRTUtil.java:146)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.loadModulesInJimage(JavaProject.java:876)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.computePackageFragmentRoots(JavaProject.java:680)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.computePackageFragmentRoots(JavaProject.java:963)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.computePackageFragmentRoots(JavaProject.java:922)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:477)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:259)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:583)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:320)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:306)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getChildren(JavaElement.java:261)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPackageFragmentRoots(JavaProject.java:2143)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.getPackageFragmentRoots(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:308)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.StandardJavaElementContentProvider.getChildren(StandardJavaElementContentProvider.java:180)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.getChildren(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:295)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1363)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getRawChildren(TreeViewer.java:341)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ProblemTreeViewer.getFilteredChildren(ProblemTreeViewer.java:251)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getSortedChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:618)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTreeViewer.java:814)
     at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:792)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:595)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:763)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.setExpandedState(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2459)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleDoubleClick(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:355)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$3.doubleClick(PackageExplorerPart.java:518)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:831)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
     at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:828)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1459)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1258)
     at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:249)
     at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:247)
     at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:306)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5268)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4522)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4107)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:531)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Comment: update:   Tried installing the slightly more up-to-date JDK from Java.com (9.0.1 for linux). I was able to register as the default/installed JRE  under Preferenced -> Java -> Installed JREs, and attempting to make a new project, but still did not work. Also I tried pointing to this specific java install in the Eclipse.ini file, to which it 'starts', but crashed when choosing a WORKSPACE, including choosing a new one... I'm thinking this might be a specific "Mint support" issue?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!
When using the Oomph installer for Eclipse, needed to point to the newly installed JDK9.0.1.... For whatever reason the "openJDK 9-Interal" that was present/defaulting wasn't working...
If anyone else struggles with a similar issue setting up eclipse on Mint, I recommend getting a clean/fresh JDK off of java.com, and carefully configure the Oomph installer (make sure both are 64-bit), and point it to this JDK instead of the default..